# vba: Export Excel to Access, remove duplicate IDs

Tags: vba

I have some experience in Excel vba but none with Access. I have created a tool in excel that does many things and ends with a tab with data in a table. Multiple people will be using excel as a data entry tool. I want the data from the final tab to export to Access so that it aggregates data across people who are inputting. To make sure not to create a mess, I need to check for duplicate IDs upon submission to Access. The ID variable is called ADP_Number and is in column 2 of Excel and Access.

The code below works to submit the data to Access but does nothing with the IDs. Can someone help me with that?

```
Sub ExportToAccess_DAO()

Dim oSelect As Range, i As Long, j As Integer ', sPath As String
Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
Sheets("Program_List").Activate
Set oSelect = Application.InputBox("Range", , Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, , , , , 8)
Dim oDAO As DAO.DBEngine
Dim oDB As DAO.Database
Dim oRS As DAO.Recordset
ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set oDAO = New DAO.DBEngine
Set oDB = oDAO.OpenDatabase("I:\ALLSHARE\MAD_14.accdb", _
False, False, "MS Access;PWD=MAD_14")
Set oRS = oDB.OpenRecordset("Program") ' change name?

For i = 2 To oSelect.Rows.Count 'skips labels
    oRS.AddNew 'addnew record to recordset
    For j = 1 To oSelect.Columns.Count ' number of columns 'Field 0 is an auto# - like an ID, so we start at 1
        oRS.Fields(j) = oSelect.Cells(i, j)
    Next j
    oRS.Update
Next i
oDB.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do two things.

Add code that runs a remove duplicates portion. Depending on the structure of you data it might be best to copy all of your data to a new tab first and use that to import. This makes sure that all of the keyed in data remains intact.

For example:

```
 Sheets.Add After:=Sheets("DATA")
 Sheets("Program_List").Select
 Range(oSelect.Range).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("DATA").Select
 Range("A1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
```

For remove duplicates you have options and to make sure you get your vba just right I would record the remove duplicates step and append that at the end of this block.

I would put this at the beginning of your code just after the ChDir line.

Another option may be to make a slight change to your Access database. This isn't always possible if you can't control the Access environment. If you can then import into a temporary table then you could write a query that only selects distinct values when inserting into the data table that you want. Your database object can run the query for you from Excel.

For example:

- In Access you need a temporary table - TEMP_TableName - this is a duplicate of the table you need the data in.
- Change you Excel VBA to use this new table.
- Create a SELECT DISTINCT query. This assumes that all of the duplicate values have the same value in all of the columns. If it doesn't then you will need to create a more complex query that uses GROUP BYS, Min/Max, Fist/Last ect to get unique values.
- Once the query returns only the values you want convert it to an append query. Select the final destination table as the append to source.
- In excel you will need a new line of code.

  ```
   oDB.OpenQuery("QueryName")
  ```

Either of these will get your data into Access without duplicates.